# How to output the results of OpenModelica simulation in a specific folder and directory?

Tags: python, openmodelica

How to address the path of results folder in the mod.buildModel() using python?

```
 model_path="C:/Users/sophie/VirtualEnv/RoomM-Model/"
 mod=ModelicaSystem(model_path + "RoomM.mo","RoomM")
 mod.buildModel()
```

Comment: You could change the working directory to a specific directory after the `ModelicaSystem` is created. It should be something like
`mod.execute("cd(\"/path/to/new/working/dir\")")`, see example from https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html#test-commands

Comment: AttributeError: 'ModelicaSystem' object has no attribute 'execute'

Comment: I could make it work using output_directory="C:/Users/sophies/VirtualEnv/RoomM-Model"
os.chdir(output_directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use build model after ModelicaSystem constructor, as ModelicaSystem will call the buildModel internally you should use simulate API to specify the result file path. So the code should be something like this

```
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
mod=ModelicaSystem(model_path + "RoomM.mo","RoomM")
mod.simulate(resultfile="room.mat") ## unfortunately you can provide the location
mod.tempdir ## this will show you the directory where the result file is located
```

you should read the documentation for the API usage https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.21/ompython.html#enhanced-ompython-features. And please open the issues directly in the git repository https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython/issues